# cpp - is vtable pointer being altered during construction/destruction

Tags: c++, vtable

So, while being in a `ctor/dtor` of a base class while doing smth with a derived class and calling member functions (including virtual), whether via `this` pointer or not, the function of the relevant class will be called.

How come? Is `vtable` pointer of the object being altered somehow during the process? Because, as I may understand it, there is generally a single `vtable` pointer in an object unless multiple inheritance is used.

---

I have the following code to exemplify what I mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>


class B {
    public:
    B()
        { printf("B constructor!\n"); f(); g(); }
    virtual ~B()
        { printf("B destructor!\n");  f(); g(); }
    virtual void f() 
        { printf("f() in B!\n"); }
    void g() 
        { printf("g() in B!\n"); }
    void h() 
        { printf("h() in B!\n"); }
};

class D : public B {
    public:
    D()
        { printf("D constructor!\n"); f(); g(); }
    virtual ~D()
        { printf("D destructor!\n");  f(); g(); }
    virtual void f() 
        { printf("f() in D!\n"); }
    void g() 
        { printf("g() in D!\n"); h(); }
};

int main()
{
    D *d = new D;
    B *b = d;
    delete b;
}
```

In ctors/dtors, the member functions of created/destructed object is called.

Comment: tl;dr: yes (although that is an implementation detail).  What you are observing is the way the language is designed to operate.

Comment: Yes, the common implementation technique is to have the constructor set the object's vtable pointer first thing. So the `B`'s constructor sets it to point to `B`s vtable, then `D`'s constructor modifies it to point to `D`'s vtable. Again, this is just the implementation detail - what matters is the standard saying that the dynamic type of the object under construction or destruction is the class whose constructor/destructor is currently running.

Comment: Yes, it's altered if you introduce new virtual functions in derived classes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An object is the type that it is... until it isn't.

Per C++'s rules, an object's constructors get called in a specific order. Because a derived class instance *is a* base class instance at all times, the base class instance constructor needs to be called before the derived class instance.

But if that's the case, then what is the object while the base class constructor is called? The derived class constructor hasn't even *started*, so it doesn't make sense to consider it a derived class instance yet.

So it isn't.

Therefore, during the period of the base class constructor's execution within a derived class's initialization, all `virtual` calls work as if that is all the class is: a base class instance. It is not *yet* an instance of the derived class type, so you cannot *yet* call any of the derived class's members.

I mean, yes, you can `static_cast` to the derived class instance, but using such a pointer yields undefined behavior, since you're accessing an object of a derived class type before that type has been initialized.

The reverse happens in destructors. The derived class destructor gets called first, then base classes. But after the derived class destructor is finished... the object is *no longer* a derived class instance. So any `virtual` calls in base class destructors go to the base class methods.

In vtable-based implementations, this behavior is implemented by changing the vtable pointer between constructors/destructors at various points during initialization. The base class constructor sets the vtable to point at the base class vtable. When the derived class destructor starts, it sets the vtable to point to the derived class vtable.

Comment: This a nice elaboration on the topic, thank you!